# Punishment of people who believed in the spies' report. How was it determined how long they should live?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

Except for Kalev and Yehoshua, everyone over age 20 was destined to die within the 40 years wandering in the desert.

Was there any criteria used as to how many more years a specific person was to live within those 40 years?

Answer (score 2):

[Rashi to 14:33](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9942#showrashi=true&v=33) says:

> לא מת אחד מהם פחות מבן שישים, לכך נגזר ארבעים, כדי שיהיו אותם של בני עשרים מגיעין לכלל ששים.
>
> Not one of them died before the age of sixty. This is why forty [years] was decreed, so that those who were twenty years old would reach the age of sixty.

Each person died at age 60.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Does this mean that everyone age 60 and above died immediately?

Comment: They were all at least 60. That's all that means. They weren't all 20 at the time they were sent were they?

Comment: @DanF The punishment was decreed on those wo were counted in the census between the ages of 20 and 60. Those under 20 or above sixty were excempt. See my answer at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40304/why-were-the-jews-punished-for-40-years-if-the-spies-were-the-ones-who-were-ther/36345#36345

Comment: @DanF According to the Kli Yakar each person who was going to die, died on the Tish'a B'Av after his sixtieth birthday.

Comment: @sabbahillel Thanks for the ref. to Kli Yakar. the answer in your link didn't completely appear to answer my question.

Comment: @DanF The point was that everyone between 20 and sixty would die and that they would die at the age of sixty. The criteria was that 20 - 60 was the age range for army service. Thus all those who were supposed to be in the army at the time of the meraglim  would die. They became scheduled to die on the Tish'a B'av following their "release" from army service (at age sixty).